# Response.Flush with MVC Result is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download

We are implementing long running process to download database content as xml with asp.net 3.

Total document generation time is about 3-5 minutes and we want to respond with first byte as soon as possible. We have overridden `System.Web.Mvc.FileResult` and are trying to do something like:

```
protected override void WriteFile(HttpResponseBase response)
{
   Stream outputStream = response.OutputStream;
   byte[] header = xmlExportService.XmlHeader();
   response.Flush();
   outputStream.Write(header, 0, header.Length);
   response.Flush();
   //// some long running generation here
}
```

On local iis under windows 7 I am gatting Save File  dialog in browser. On production, windows server 2008 R2 there is no dialog until whole file is generated.

Any ideas?

Comment: could be a proxy interfering with the response (e.g. my corporate proxy always strips gzip encoding off a response; so I can't test our public sites to ensure that they are compressing responses from behind our proxy)

Comment: Have you checked the value of `BufferOutput` property on `HttpResponseBase`. If it's set to `true` then that may prevent your partial response being sent to client. Though this does not explain how it works locally.

Comment: You probably should do it using Async Controllers, In that way ouy could better control Response of large files, try to search in msdn links like this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598.aspx

Comment: Save File may indicate that the Response Type is defaulting to a binary type rather than xml. Again, odd that it would happen in one but not the other.

Comment: Probably due to 'IE Extreme Lockdown' mode that is default on all server products. Try another browser or change the IE security settings.

Comment: Could the following link be of any help? http://forums.asp.net/t/1562626.aspx/1

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if this helps anyone, but Response.Flush will not "work" if you have HTTP compression enabled.  We enabled dynamic compression on our servers and the call to Response.Flush would just hang.  After some research, it has to do with the fact that the server is waiting for all the output so it can "compress it and send it".

Since we are using MVC, I am considering using an attribute to dynamically control if compression is enabled for non-static pages.  For now, we just got rid of the Response.Flush call in our Views.

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this postings? Same questions, accepted answers, might be of help?

- [MVC 3 Response.Flush does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007896/mvc-3-response-flush-does-not-work)
- [Response.Flush not working ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344430/response-flush-not-working-asp-net)